# Excel recovered unreadable content (worksheet) as class and can't be deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tracking tool that follows a process at work over a 14 week cycle. When we start a new cycle of the process (approximately 50 times per year) we use the latest template to create a new tracking file (updated 4-5 times per year with improvements and bug fixes).

This morning we received the *Excel found unreadable content...* error message opening a particular instance of the tool halfway through the cycle. Upon "recovering" the file Excel then identifies what was affected and that data is not recovered.

[image: Recovery message box]

The lost data is generic and of no value, however with the macros and formulas developed the SHEET NAME is.

The problem comes by way of the "recovered" sheet being morphed into a class I cannot delete. There are a lot of formulas and macros that reference this sheet and they CANNOT be changed at this stage.

[image: Project Explorer screenshot with right-click menu]

I even tried unzipping the .xlsx package and removing the offending worksheet, rels, etc., but can't seem to clear it all.

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt to use that file. The object you have selected appears to have the name and properties of `ThisWorkbook` (which is in keeping with the icon displayed) in spite of appearing to be a worksheet.

Comment: Unfortunately in this corporate environment our systems are locked down and I'm unable to utilise LibreOffice, OpenOffice. The same goes for restrictions of transferring to another computer for rectifying.